# How to search for const pointer in a collection of non-const pointers?

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I have a member variable `std::set<T*> m_associates;`, i.e., a collection of non-const raw pointers, and simply want to check for existence of another pointer.
To maintain const correctness my function looks like this:

```
bool MyClass::is_associated(const T* x) const
{
    return (m_associates.find(x) != m_associates.end());
}
```

However, this does not compile, since `x` is passed as `const T*` to indicate that the value pointed to by `x` is not changed by the function, but `m_associates` contains non-const `T*`.

If I remove `const` from the `x` parameter, it compiles, but violates const correctness...

Adding `const` to `m_associates`, i.e., `std::set<const T*> m_associates;` is not an option either as I need the non-const pointers elsewhere in my class.

How do I solve this? Is this (possibly the only) point where a `const_cast` should be used? Or do I have to always pass all parameter `T` pointers as non-const?

Edit:
Full error output, compiler is clang++-8, code is in C++17

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
        return (m_associates.find(x) != m_associates.end());
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_set.h:798:7: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const T *') would lose const qualifier
      find(const key_type& __x) const
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_set.h:804:2: note: candidate function template not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::set<T *>', but method is not marked const
        find(const _Kt& __x)
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_set.h:794:7: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::set<T *>', but method is not marked const
      find(const key_type& __x)
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_set.h:810:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Kt = const T *]: no matching member function for call to '_M_find_tr'
        find(const _Kt& __x) const
        ^
```

Comment: There should be no issue with *adding* const here. You should definitely not violate const-correcteness.

Comment: What error do you get from the posted code?

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using? C++14 and above would allow for this to work if you use a transparent comparator on the `std::set`

Comment: Using C++17 with clang++-8, I added the error output to the main text

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason your current code fails is that the default `Compare` for `std::set<T>` is `std::less<T>`; which forces both arguments to be a `T` for comparison -- in this case, non-`const` `T*` types. Since `const T*` cannot be converted to `T*` without casting away the constness, this is causing your compile errors.

If you are using C++14 or above, you can redefine your `std::set` so that the `Compare` template type is a transparent comparator (one that deduces the underlying types for comparison), for example `std::set<T*, std::less<>>`. This will enable the overload of [`std::set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) that deduces the type and forwards the argument to the comparator, which will enable the above code to work.

Comment: That's nice. Have an upvote. (Personally I think the C++ tag has sort of moved to C++14 now. Even me with my fuddy duddy ness programs to C++14 now.)

Comment: At work my environment is stuck on C++11 still (almost a decade old now...), so I try not to assume!

Comment: This works, but forces me to add the additional template parameter to many parts of my codebase which makes it a little more difficult to read...
Or it forces me to introduce a new type alias via `using`...
Do you have any ideas how to solve this without far reaching changes to the codebase?

Comment: @Bathsheba `That's nice. Have an upvote.` always a pleasure to see a gentleman on S.O. UV both answers

Comment: @Gileos Unfortunately, this is the _only_ way to solve this problem using `std::set::find` without a `const_cast`. If this is too invasive of a change, the only way to use this function would be to `const_cast` the `const T*` to a `T*` so that the comparison may work, or just not use `std::set::find` (such as sub-optimally searching via `std::find` instead)

Comment: @Gileos type aliases are good. Makes code support easier and saves people from trying to wade through forests of chevrons (< > pairs).

Comment: @Human-Compiler alright thank you so much for the quick reply :)

Comment: @Gileos np! If changing `std::set` _is_ possible, you should consider using aliases as was suggested above. `std::set<T,std::less<>>` is far more powerful than `std::set<T,std::less<T>>` since it allows heterogeneous comparisons, and as a result it is a much better default. The only reason `std::set<T>` defaults `Compare` to `std::less<T>` is for compatibility with earlier standards.

Comment: This is one of my favourite "C++ is kinda dumb"isms!

Comment: FWIW I usually just go with the `const_cast`. It's not so bad if it's buried in an accessor/utility function with a massive apology comment around it

Comment: @Human-Compiler can you also tell me how to apply such a tweak to a `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: I don't believe `unordered_set` has (or even can have) an equivalent -- so here you would have to use `const_cast`. The comparator solution works with non-hash containers because you can determine identity through equivalent types that allow it (like comparing a `const char*` to a `std::string`). The same is not necessarily true of hashes in a hash container (something like `1` is not the same hash as `1.0`). Even though we're only talking about `const` pointers here, it's a very specific special case

Answer (score 4):

You can cast away the `const`-ness of `x` with no ill-effects in this case.

Other than perhaps signalling a design flaw, the *only* thing you need to watch out with casting away `const` is that the behaviour on attempting to modify an object that was originally declared using `const` via the non-`const` pointer is undefined. That's not the case here.